# How get Subocllection Reference in Firestore

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an exaple structure in my Firestore like this:
document User and document Perfumes. User can have FavouritePerfumes collection and there an Ids of Perfumes document. How can I get fvourite Perfumes properties like : name and brad for specific user?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the data directly from the `favoritePerfumes` sub-collection when you already have the userId, you can actually chain it to the `documentReference` of it's parent and use a `get()` to do it.

Here is an example you can apply to your case:

```
var documentReference = db.collection("users").document(userId)
documentReference.collection("favoritePerfumes")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
           for (document in result) {
              var name = document.get("name")
              var brand = document.get("brand")
              Log.d(TAG, "The name is ${name} and the brand is ${brand}")
            }
          }
         .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents:", exception)
          }
```